# How to install WIne on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, wine, 20.04

Can't Find wine in Ubuntu store. How can i install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64 BIT)?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal, and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine
```

Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is in the Software app in Ubuntu 20.04 with the other applications that are installable by apt, but first you need to install the Software app in order to find it. Wine is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot.

To install the Software app open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

[image]

Alternatively you can install Wine from the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine winetricks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine64
```

[This](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu/) tutorial is for Ubuntu 18.04, but it still works for 20.04. I'm using it every time I need to install Wine.